# sqlite connection uses username and password

Tags: laravel, sqlite

The MySQLite connection uses a username and password but I didn't specify any

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `customers`)

Comment: Can you share your `.env` file?

Comment: "MySQLite"? What database are you using?

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=sqlite   
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1   
DB_PORT=3306   
DB_DATABASE=database/database.sqlite   
DB_USERNAME=homestead  
DB_PASSWORD=secret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error basically comes from changing the `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` in `.env` file

Open the `.env` file and edit it.

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME=           // Your Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password
```

The `DB_USERNAME` should be set to `root` if you do not have a default username in the installation time.

NOTE: If no password is set on the database, clear it `DB_PASSWORD`,

After `.env` edit, must be clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: the command fixed it,, i guess it needed a refresh or something